# Difference between document.getElementById(hello).innerHTML to hello.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

So recently I discovered that document.getElementById(hello).innerHTML and hello.innerHTML gives me the same effect in a javascript code. So why use the first one if the second is viable? Is there a risk of using just hello.innerHTML?

Comment: What is `hello` exactly? I assume it's a variable...if so, what is its value?

Comment: I bet you mean `getElementById('hello')`...

Comment: @FelixKling no i mean in an html there is an element with id="hello" and in javascript in one case i state a var (lets say var meow) =document.getelementbyid("hello") and i use meow.innerHTML = "poop". in the other case I dont state a variable at all to define the id and i just use the id itself to change the innerhtml (since the id is hello) i will put hello.innerHTML. hello is not a variable or anything, its just an id within the html code, and It works!

Comment: @dhira no i mean in an html there is an element with id="hello" and in javascript in one case i state a var (lets say var meow) =document.getelementbyid("hello") and i use meow.innerHTML = "poop". in the other case I dont state a variable at all to define the id and i just use the id itself to change the innerhtml (since the id is hello) i will put hello.innerHTML. hello is not a variable or anything, its just an id within the html code, and It works

Comment: You wrote in your question `getElementById(hello)`, which means passing the **variable** `hello` to `getElementById`. As you confirmed, you are passing a string instead (`getElementById('hello')`) which was the whole point of my comment. Passing a string is very different from passing a variable though. Please make sure the information in your question also reflects what you are doing.